# Send whole content of .txt (500+lines) in discord chat? javascript/discordbot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, chat, sendmessage

I want to show the whole content of a txt with 500+ lines on discord chat but discord has a limit of characters per message - must be fewer than 2000 in length.

I was only able to show the first 175 lines using the code bellow. I used split[separator][limit].
How can I send the rest of the file content in the chat?

```
 if (message.content === '!list') {
   var text = fs.readFileSync('list.txt', 'utf8');
    let vvv = text.split(',',175);
     message.channel.send(text);
```

Comment: You can split your text file into multiple message and send it multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`split` parameter on `MessageOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) passed to `TextChannel.send()` you can split messages and specify the maximum length if you wish.